# Can we export data from kusto to SQL using windows authentication?

Tags: sql, export, azure-data-explorer

I am trying to export data from kusto to sql. I see that there is an option of 'Authentication=Active Directory Integrated'. But can we do it with just windows authentication?

```
.export async to sql ['dbo.MySqlTable']
    h@"Server=tcp:abc.database.windows.net,1433;Database=xyz;Authentication=Windows;Connection Timeout=30;"
    with (createifnotexists="true", primarykey="id")
    <|set notruncation;
```

Answer (score 0):

No, Kusto only supports 'Active Directory Integrated' and SQL credentials.

Comment: "Windows" means you are going to pick up the identity that is currently logged in to Windows, but since the command is interpreted and run by the Kusto service, there is no such identity, and that's why this mode is not supported.